# Coloring of rectangle $3\times 4$

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

> We are colorings fields of rectangle with $3$ rows and $4$ columns in use of $2$ colors. Two colorings are the same if one is created from second in use any permutation of rows and cyclic shift of columns. Find number of different colorings, in which each color is used $6$ times.

A = \begin{bmatrix}
    a & a & a \\
    a & a & a \\
    b & b & b \\
    b & b & b
\end{bmatrix}
$A^T$ give me $1$ coloring.
A = \begin{bmatrix}
    a & a & a \\
    a & a & b \\
    a & b & b \\
    b & b & b
\end{bmatrix}
$A^T$ give me $1$ coloring.
A = \begin{bmatrix}
    a & a & b \\
    a & a & b \\
    a & a & b \\
    b & b & b
\end{bmatrix}
$A^T$ give me $1$ coloring.
A = \begin{bmatrix}
    a & a & b \\
    a & a & b \\
    a & b & b \\
    a & b & b
\end{bmatrix}

$A^T$ give me $1$ coloring.
etc... But is there any smarter  way to do this? Writing all combinations is really slow and will cause an mistake so... I would like to see how to solve tasks like this when we are coloring structure with additional conditions.

Comment: In task I mistaken in drawing matrices so I add $T$

Comment: Does "cyclic shift of columns" mean that $$ \begin{bmatrix}
     b & b & & \\
     b & b & & \\
     b & b & &
 \end{bmatrix}\ \text{and} \ \begin{bmatrix}
     b & & b &  \\
     b & & b &  \\
     b & & b & 
 \end{bmatrix}$$ are two different ways of colorings?

Comment: Yes, I understand this in exactly that way @Tianlalu

Answer (score 1):

Here  is a  computational  contribution that  treats  the problem  for
matrices with dimenstion  $n$ rows by $m$ columns,  with the symmetric
group  permuting  the   rows  and  the  cyclic   group  permuting  the
columns. As  pointed out this  problem can  be solved using  the Polya
Enumeration Theorem.  We  just need to compute the cycle  index of the
group acting on the slots of the matrix.

These cycle indices are easy to compute  and we do not need to iterate
over  all $n!\times  m$  pairs  of permutations  (acting  on rows  and
columns) but instead  it is sufficient to iterate over  pairs of terms
from the  cycle index $Z(S_n)$  of the  symmetric group $S_n$  and the
cycle  index  $Z(C_m)$   of  the  cyclic  group   according  to  their
multiplicities to obtain the cycle  index $Z(Q_{n,m})$ of the combined
action on  rows and  columns.  The  number of terms  here is  the much
better  count of  the number  of partitions  of $n$  times $m$  (upper
bound).

Now for a pair  of cycles, one of length $l_1$  from a row permutation
$\alpha$ and another of length $l_2$ from a column permutation $\beta$
their  contribution to  the disjoint  cycle decomposition  product for
$(\alpha,\beta)$  in the cycle index  $Z(Q_{n,m})$  is  by  inspection
$$a_{\mathrm{lcm}(l_1,  l_2)}^{l_1  l_2  / \mathrm{lcm}(l_1,  l_2)}  =
a_{\mathrm{lcm}(l_1, l_2)}^{\gcd(l_1, l_2)}.$$

The algorithm now  becomes very simple -- iterate over  pairs of terms
as described above, collect the  contribution from each pair of cycles
and add it to the cycle index being computed.

This  gives the  following  cycle  indices:

$$Z(Q_{3,4}) = 
1/24\,{a_{{1}}}^{12}+1/6\,{a_{{2}}}^{6}+1/3\,{a_{{4}}
}^{3}\\+1/8\,{a_{{1}}}^{4}{a_{{2}}}^{4}+1/12\,{a_{{3}}}
^{4}+1/12\,{a_{{6}}}^{2}+1/6\,a_{{12}}$$

and

$$Z(Q_{4,3}) =
{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{12}}{72}}+1/4\,{a_{{3}}}^{4}+1/12
\,{a_{{1}}}^{6}{a_{{2}}}^{3}+1/6\,{a_{{3}}}^{2}a_{{6}
}\\+1/9\,{a_{{1}}}^{3}{a_{{3}}}^{3}+1/24\,{a_{{2}}}^{6}
+1/12\,{a_{{6}}}^{2}+1/12\,{a_{{4}}}^{3}+1/6\,a_{{12}}.$$

The PET-substituted cycle indices are

$$Z(Q_{3,4}; A+B) = 
{A}^{12}+{A}^{11}B+5\,{A}^{10}{B}^{2}+12\,{A}^{9}{B}^
{3}\\+28\,{A}^{8}{B}^{4}+38\,{A}^{7}{B}^{5}+48\,{A}^{6}
{B}^{6}+38\,{A}^{5}{B}^{7}+28\,{A}^{4}{B}^{8}\\+12\,{A}
^{3}{B}^{9}+5\,{A}^{2}{B}^{10}+A{B}^{11}+{B}^{12}$$

and

$$Z(Q_{4,3}; A+B) = 
{A}^{12}+{A}^{11}B+3\,{A}^{10}{B}^{2}+8\,{A}^{9}{B}^{
3}\\+14\,{A}^{8}{B}^{4}+19\,{A}^{7}{B}^{5}+24\,{A}^{6}{
B}^{6}+19\,{A}^{5}{B}^{7}\\+14\,{A}^{4}{B}^{8}+8\,{A}^{
3}{B}^{9}+3\,{A}^{2}{B}^{10}+A{B}^{11}+{B}^{12}.$$

We thus have the desired answer that  for a matrix that is $3\times 4$
we obtain with $A$ and $B$ each used six times

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{48}$$

colorings and for a $4\times 3$,

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{24.}$$

This is  the Maple code for  this computation, which also  includes an
enumeration routine to verify the output  from PET for small values of
the parameters.

```
with(numtheory);

pet_cycleind_cyclic :=
n -> add(phi(d)*a[d]^(n/d), d in divisors(n))/n;


pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subs2, polyvars, indvars, v, pot, res;

    res := ind;

    polyvars := indets(poly);
    indvars := indets(ind);

    for v in indvars do
        pot := op(1, v);

        subs1 :=
        [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
             k=1..nops(polyvars))];

        subs2 := [v=subs(subs1, poly)];

        res := subs(subs2, res);
    od;

    res;
end;


pet_cycleind_mat :=
proc(n, m)
option remember;
local rowind, colind, cind, term_a, term_b, v_a, v_b,
    len_a, len_b, inst_a, inst_b, p;

    cind := 0;

    if n=1 then
        return pet_cycleind_cyclic(m);
    else
        rowind := pet_cycleind_symm(n);
    fi;

    if m=1 then
        return pet_cycleind_symm(n);
    else
        colind := pet_cycleind_cyclic(m);
    fi;

    for term_a in rowind do
        for term_b in colind do
            p := 1;
            for v_a in indets(term_a) do
                len_a := op(1, v_a);
                inst_a := degree(term_a, v_a);

                for v_b in indets(term_b) do
                    len_b := op(1, v_b);
                    inst_b := degree(term_b, v_b);

                    p := p*a[lcm(len_a, len_b)]
                    ^(gcd(len_a, len_b)*inst_a*inst_b);
                od;
            od;

            cind := cind +
            lcoeff(term_a)*lcoeff(term_b)*p;
        od;
    od;

    cind;
end;

v :=
proc(n, m)
    option remember;
    local cind, vars, sbl;

    cind := pet_cycleind_mat(n, m);

    vars := indets(cind);
    sbl := [seq(v=2, v in vars)];

    subs(sbl, cind);
end;

colors_AB :=
proc(n, m)
    option remember;
    local cind;

    cind := pet_cycleind_mat(n, m);

    expand(pet_varinto_cind(A+B, cind));
end;

with(combinat);

colors_AB_verif :=
proc(n, m)
option remember;
local idx, d, mat, pmat, orbit, orbits,
    gf, cnt, rperm, c, cperm;

    orbits := table();

    for idx from 2^(n*m) to 2^(n*m+1)-1 do
        d := convert(idx, base, 2)[1..n*m];

        mat := [seq([seq(d[p*m+q+1], q=0..m-1)],
                    p=0..n-1)];

        orbit := [];

        rperm := firstperm(n);
        while type(rperm, `list`) do
            for c to m do
                cperm :=
                [seq(p, p=c..m), seq(p, p=1..c-1)];

                pmat :=
                [seq([seq(mat[rperm[p]][cperm[q]],
                          q=1..m)], p=1..n)];

                orbit := [op(orbit), pmat];
            od;

            rperm := nextperm(rperm);
        od;

        orbits[sort(orbit)[1]] := 1;
    od;

    gf := 0;

    for orbit in [indices(orbits, 'nolist')] do
        cnt := add(add(orbit[p][q], p=1..n), q=1..m);
        gf := gf + A^cnt * B^(n*m-cnt);
    od;

    gf;
end;
```

This [MSE Link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22159/)
has a very similar PET computation.