# Count the number of unique $N \times N$ binary matrices where every two rows or columns can be swapped

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, combinations, integer-partitions

Suppose, two $n\times n$ binary matrices are $\it similar$ if one can be transformed to another by swapping any two rows or two columns any number of times.

My problem is: how many unique $n\times n$ binary matrices with a given number of 1s are there ? That is, those that are not $\it similar$ to any other matrix using the definition above?

For example, there are 7 unique $3\times 3$ matrices having 4 ones:

$\begin{array}{|ccc|}\hline
1 & 1 & .\\
1 & 1 & .\\
. & . & .\\\hline\end{array}
\begin{array}{|ccc|}\hline
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & . & .\\
. & . & .\\\hline\end{array} 
\begin{array}{|ccc|}\hline
1 & 1 & .\\
1 & . & 1\\
. & . & .\\\hline\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{|ccc|}\hline
1 & 1 & .\\
1 & . & .\\
1 & . & .\\\hline\end{array} 
\begin{array}{|ccc|}\hline
. & 1 & 1\\
1 & . & .\\
1 & . & .\\\hline\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{|ccc|}\hline
1 & 1 & .\\
1 & . & .\\
. & 1 & .\\\hline\end{array}
\begin{array}{|ccc|}\hline
1 & 1 & .\\
1 & . & .\\
. & . & 1\\\hline\end{array}$

What I came up with is that two $\it similar$ matrices would have the same
(sorted) column sums and row sums but, apparently, this is not enough.
From the example above, one can see that the three last matrices:

$\begin{array}{|ccc|}\hline
. & 1 & 1\\
1 & . & .\\
1 & . & .\\\hline\end{array}  
\begin{array}{|ccc|}\hline
1 & 1 & .\\
1 & . & .\\
. & 1 & .\\\hline\end{array}
\begin{array}{|ccc|}\hline
1 & 1 & .\\
1 & . & .\\
. & . & 1\\\hline\end{array}$

would have $(2, 2, 1)$ rows sum and $(2, 2, 1)$ column sum.

There is some similarity with Young diagrams and conjugate/self-conjugate integer partitions.. but the idea how to count these matrices I do not understand, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can embedd the symmteric groups inside $GL(n,k)$ for a field $k$, these are the permutation matrices .. this being the case, seems like you are looking at the action of $S_n \times S_n$ on the matrices by $(P,Q) \cdot A = PAQ^{-1}$ .. so in principle you could use orbit stabilizer theorem to answer what you are looking for .. but perhaps there are cleverer ways to count .. we can wait for other answers

Comment: Duplicate of [How many $n\times m$ binary matrices are there, up to row and column permutations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/22159/318073) ? (See [A002724](https://oeis.org/A002724).)

Comment: @asm, here is the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4620880/is-there-a-way-to-calculate-the-number-of-equivalence-classes-given-the-number-o)